# How can I view a live volume meter?

Tags: sound, volume-control

I want visual feedback of the sound that is currently coming out of the computer. How can I view a live volume meter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple VU-meter-like graphical feedback is provided by [pavucontrol](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol] 
or by [pavumeter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pavumeter) [image: Install pavumeter]

Comment: Neither of these show any movement while sound is playing. Is some kind of extra setup required?

Comment: That's weird. I took the shots while they wer bumping happily. This in 10.04, 10.10, 11.04. Hmm

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. No movement in pavucontrol or pavumeter when playing sound from Banshee, Clementine, or YouTube (npviewer.bin) in two different 11.04 installations. pavucontrol lists each in the playback tab, just like your screenshot.

Comment: But you do hear a sound? For me the signal levels work fine in 10.04, 10.10, 11.04 on two different boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you have to have the audio device "output monitor" (an input device) level up, for any real-time indication in Pavucontrol to work for output sounds.