# How can I make Ubuntu compatible with baudline?

Tags: 11.04, sound, microphone, soundcard, devices

When I run [baudline](http://www.baudline.com/), it displays the message "all input devices disabled" and the Input ▸ Devices screen doesn't list any devices. The [baudline FAQ](http://www.baudline.com/faq.html#no_devices) suggests:

> Here are two possible explanations for this:
>
> 1. You don't have a properly configured audio card.
> 2. Or you don't have read and write privileges for /dev/audio or /dev/mixer.

The observation that sound works in every other program I've tried (though there is [one exception](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44000/how-can-i-view-a-live-volume-meter/44023#44023)) strongly suggests that my sound card is properly configured.

The problem appears to be related to `/dev/audio` and `/dev/mixer`. I'm certain that I do not have read and write privileges for them, because they don't even exist. I think [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/579300/+index?comments=all) is responsible for their absence, but I'm not sure what it means for me.

I have used baudline in Ubuntu in past years without any problems. How can I make Ubuntu's sound configuration compatible with baudline again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My fix was to run it like this

```
parec --format=s16le --channels=1 --latency-msec=5 | ./baudline -stdin
```

This uses parec to read from pulseaudio and pipes it to baudline.

Comment: Of course! I should have thought of this.

Comment: For such workarounds I usually create a new executable eg. baudline_wrap to permanently wrap the old one and to symlink to eg. usr/bin/baudline.  Content: 

`#!/bin/sh` newline
`PROGRAM_DIRECTORY="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"` newline 
`parec --format=s16le --channels=1 --latency-msec=5 | "$PROGRAM_DIRECTORY/baudline" -stdin  "$@"`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps possible three choices:

- See if the PulseAudio OSS Wrapper works with baudline e.g.

  `padsp baudline -stdout > file.raw`
- Install a dual boot with ArchLinux

reading through the baudline FAQ is makes it mentions working with ALSA with OSS support.  I would read that as needing a kernel with OSS support. Canonical removed this support from maverick and natty.  Arch still has OSS support built into their linux kernel (I think)

- compile your own kernel with the OSS flags (the flags in the bug report) with instructions such as in [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-customize-your-ubuntu-kernel/)

Answer (score 1):

I loaded theese modules

- `snd-pcm-oss`
- `snd-pcm-mixer`

and added in `/etc/modules`

Now baudline works, can analyze and play audio