# How to tell if sound is playing before I unmute

Tags: 14.04

It's really annoying to have sound playing through my speakers when I un-mute when it seems the coast is clear.

Comment: have you looked [HERE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44000/how-can-i-view-a-live-volume-meter) yet. This may work for what you want.

Comment: @JohnOrion It doesn't work when muted

Comment: Doh!!! yeah that makes sense .. its measuring the volume and there is none when its muted ... sorry .. wasn't thinking. To be honest .. that's quite a question you have there... if its muted then there is no volume ... so how can anything tell ... unless its something that scans all programs that could produce audio to see if they are producing any. Not sure anything like that exists

Comment: @JohnOrion I was hoping it would be some feature built into Ubuntu

Comment: What types of sounds are you talking about ... like if you unmute it and don't realize that the webpage is playing a video or ad with sound? Usually I pretty much know if something is going to start making sound when I unmute the system.

Comment: @JohnOrion I usually have a bunch of VLC windows open with paused music and it's difficult to sort through them all to see if any are actively playing music.

Comment: I think i may be able to help .. it may work but it may not ... if you open system monitor and open a bunch of vlc ... have one playing when muted and see if one of the vlc's are more active ... if so .. you may be able to use a script to check for activity past a limit and tell you that one is producing sound

Comment: Yep Zalethon got it right ... its exactly what you are looking for and it probably is already installed .. it was on my system already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and run `pavucontrol`. This is a graphical mixer for pulseaudio, and displays which devices sound is playing on, among other things.

Comment: Does not work while muted

Comment: man i was close . .but sure enough .. this is exactly what you need

Comment: this is pavucontrol not pavumeter and pavucontrol does show when muted

Comment: If the device is muted, pavucontrol still shows you which applications are playing sound.